# How to create trigger after update to get the value totalPayment

Tags: oracle

I want to create a trigger to calculate the totalPayment on Event table.
But to calculate the totalPayment column, it a references with another two table which is Location and Equipment. Below is the table structure for the tables:

```
create table equipment(
equipmentID varchar2(10) primary key,
equipmentName varchar2(50) not null,
equipmentPriceUnit decimal(18,2) not null
);

create table location(
locationID varchar2(10) primary key,
locationName varchar2(50) not null,
locationMaxCapacity int not null,
locationPriceHour decimal(18,2) not null
);

create table event(
eventID varchar2(10) primary key,
eventName varchar2(50) not null,
eventDurationHour int not null,
noAudience int not null,
equipmentID references equipment(equipmentID) null,
equipmentQuantity int null,
locationID references location(locationID) null,
**totalPayment decimal(18,2) null**
);
```

the equation to do this calculation is

```
totallocation := locationPriceHour*eventDurationHour;
totalequipment := equipmentPriceUnit*equipmentQuantity;
totalPayment :=totallocation + totalequipment;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_event_update
AFTER UPDATE ON event
FOR EACH ROW
REFERENCING new AS new old AS old
DECLARE
  totalLocation location.locationPriceHour%TYPE;
  totalequipment equipment.equipmentPriceUnit%TYPE;
  ... -- declaration variables
BEGIN
  SELECT l.locationPriceHour * :new.eventDurationHour
    INTO totalLocation
    FROM location
   WHERE locationID = :new.locationID;

  SELECT e.equipmentPriceUnit * :new.equipmentQuantity
    INTO totalequipment
    FROM equipment
   WHERE equipmentID = :new.equipmentID;

  :new.totalPayment := totalLocation + totalequipment;

END;
/
```

I would suggest not to use the calculated field. Calculate the values at runtime instead, like this:

```
SELECT (SELECT l.locationPriceHour
          FROM location l
         WHERE l.locationID = ev.locationID) * ev.eventDurationHour
       + (SELECT eq.equipmentPriceUnit
            FROM equipment eq
           WHERE eq.equipmentID = ev.equipmentID) * ev.equipmentQuantity
       AS totalPayment
  FROM event ev;
```

Comment: thnks but I got this error ORA-04079: invalid trigger specification

Comment: i also prefer the second step.. I have try to run it and its work!.. But, how to store the totalPayment value on the Event Table using that query?

Comment: Do you really need to store the value for totalPayment?

Comment: Read more about Oracle triggers here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/triggers.htm and make changes to the first few lines accordingly.

Comment: yess.. i need to store the value of totalPayment on the eventTable.. Ok, thnks !

Comment: Rachcha can u help me to store the totalPayment value on event table? I have try that but unsuccessful.. help me

Comment: Have you tried my solution? What is the error that it's giving? Please post the detailed error in your question as an **EDIT**.